# Angularjs form passed through Ng-repeat shows values undefined

Tags: angularjs

Angularjs form passed through Ng-repeat shows value undefined.

I have the form below which I passed through angularjs ng-repeat. when I click on submit button, it alerts values **undefined** for variable **PID,Username and email**.If I take the form outside ng-repeat, everything works. can someone help me fix the issue. thanks

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>


</head>

<body ng-app='myapp'>
  <div class="content" ng-controller='fetchCtrl'>
    <div class="post" ng-repeat='post in posts'>




            <table>

<tr>
                    <td>post Id</td>
                    <td><input type='text' id='pid' ng-model='pid' value="{{post.id}}"></td>
                </tr>


                <tr>
                    <td>First Name</td>
                    <td><input type='text' id='username' ng-model='username'></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name</td>
                    <td><input type='text' id='useremail' ng-model='useremail'></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type='button' id='but_save' value='Save' ng-click="submitButton()" ></td>
                </tr>
            </table>





      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Script -->
  <script src="angular.min.js"></script>




 <script>
        var fetch = angular.module('myapp', []);

        fetch.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {


            // Add new record
            $scope.submitButton = function(){
var username=$scope.username;
var email=$scope.useremail;
var pid=$scope.pid;

//alert variables values that is all I want
alert(username);
alert(email);
alert(pid);


// do http thing here if you like

             $http({   

            });


            }
// Fetch post data scope goes here

        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of always have a '.' in your ng-models

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions works